# Hiding Android Default Keyboard

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and C#:

I have created a custom keyboard with Keyboardview and would like to disable the Android default softkeyboard from ever popping up.

This activity contains around 60 lines of EditText.

This doesn't seem to work, it will appear once I click on another EditText.

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden);
```

My KeyboardView:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle){

  Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden);

  base.OnCreate (bundle);

  SetContentView (Resource.Layout.ORDER);
  mKeyboardView = this.FindViewById<KeyboardView> (Resource.Id.keyboardview);
  mKeyboardView.Keyboard = mKeyboard;
  mKeyboardView.PreviewEnabled = false;

  var keyboardListener = new MyKeyboardListener(this);

  mKeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener = keyboardListener;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to give you advice without knowing what you're trying to do. All ways to remove the soft keyboard will end up as some kind of dirty hack and might have consequences for your app. So here's my question:
What SHOULD happen when you focus your EditText's?

Comment: Nothing should happen as I have a custom keyboard which would be there always. The problem now is that there are 2 keyboards on the screen, my custom keyboard and the default one, I would like to disable the default one from showing. I just want it to be disabled in a single activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method on click, hide the system keyboard, and then call your a custom keyboard:

```
private void MakeEditable(bool isEditable, EditText et)
    {
        var imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);

        if (isEditable)
        {
            et.Focusable = true;
            et.Enabled = true;
            et.Clickable = true;
            et.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
            et.SetSelection(et.Text.Length);
            et.RequestFocus();
            imm.ShowSoftInput(et, ShowFlags.Implicit);
        }
        else
        {
            et.Focusable = false;
            et.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
            et.Clickable = true;
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(et.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        }
    }
```